# Iterate through vector and convert elements to unquoted variable names

Tags: sas, sas-macro

The following macro makes an inner join between two tables containing one column from each table in addition to the joining column :

```
%macro ij(x=,y=,to=".default",xc=,yc=,by=);
  %if &to   = ".default" %then %let to = &from;
  PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE &to AS
    SELECT t1.&xc, t2.&yc, t1.&by
    FROM &x t1 INNER JOIN &y t2
    ON t1.&by = t2.&by;
  RUN;
%mend;
```

I want to find a way to use several columns in `&xc`, `&yc` and `&by`.
As I don't think I can use vectors of variables.

My idea is to pass parameters as vectors of strings instead of simple variables, for example `xc = {"col1" "col2"}` and loop through them 
using `%let some_var= %sysfunc(dequote(&some_string));` to convert them back to variables.

Applied on `xc` only it would become something like:

```
%macro ij(x=,y=,to=".default",xc=,yc=,by=);
  %if &to   = ".default" %then %let to = &from;
  PROC SQL;
    CREATE TABLE &to AS
    SELECT 
    %do i = 1 %to %NCOL(&xc)
      %let xci = %sysfunc(dequote(&xc[1]));
      t1.&xci,
    %end;
    t2.&yc, t1.&by
    FROM &x t1 INNER JOIN &y t2
    ON t1.&by = t2.&by;
  RUN;
%mend;
```

But this loop fails. How could I make it work ?

*Note: this is a simplified example, my ultimate ambition is to build join macros that would be as little verbose as possible and integrate data quality checks.*

Comment: Did you try just using NATURAL join?  That will join on any variables that have the same name in both tables. http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=sqlproc&docsetTarget=p1bk7i6jqseje7n1lifcip8kzhpp.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#p1gxcf1h74qompn1x1aplq80gcvv

Comment: I didn't know about it and it seems like something I'll definitely use at some point, but I'd really like to be able to select my variables easily on both side (negatively too, as in "take all except this and that"). Basically I come from `R` and in my company we have decades of SAS code written in 1000s lines copy pastes with no macro library or structure whatsoever, it's hell. I just want to be able to write readable code and writing macros to do joins and quality checks in one line with smart default parameters seems a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really this would be much easier to code use SAS dataset options instead of building complicated macro logic.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want2 as
  select *
  from sashelp.class(keep=name age)
  natural inner join sashelp.class(keep=name height weight)
  ;
quit;
```

I would suggest learning how to use data step code instead of SQL code. For most normal data manipulations it is clearer and simpler.  Say you wanted to combine IN1 and IN2 on the variable ID and keep the variable A and B from IN1 and the variable X and Y from the IN2.

```
data out ;
  merge in1 in2 ;
  by id ;
  keep id a b x y ;
run;
```

Second I would resist the urge to generate too complex a web of macro code.  It will make the programs harder to understand for the next programmer.  Including yourself two weeks later.  Your particular example does not look like something that is worth coding as a macro. You are not really typing less information, just using a few commas in place of where your SQL code would have had keywords like FROM or JOIN.

Now to answer your actual question.  To pass in a list of values to macro use a delimited list. When at all possible use space as the delimiter, but especially avoid using comma as the delimiter. This will be easier to type, easier to pass into the macro and easier to use since it matches the SAS language as you can see in the data step above.  If you really need to generate code like SQL syntax that uses commas then have the macro code generate them where needed.

```
%macro ij
(x=    /* First dataset name */
,y=    /* Second dataset name */
,by=   /* BY variable list */
,to=   /* Output dataset name. If empty use data step to generate DATAn work name */
,xc=   /* Variable list from first dataset */
,yc=   /* Variable list from second dataset */
);
%if not %length(&to) %then %do;
* Let SAS generate a name for new dataset ;
  data ; run;
  %let to=&syslast ;
  proc delete data=&to; run;
%end;
%if not %length(&xc) %then %let xc=*;
%if not %length(&yc) %then %let yx=*;
%local i sep ;
proc sql ;
 create table &to as
   select
%let sep= ;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&by)) ;
  &sep.T1.%scan(&by,&i)
  %let sep=,;
%end;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&xc)) ;
  &sep.T1.%scan(&xc,&i)
%end;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&yc)) ;
  &sep.T2.%scan(&yc,&i)
%end;
   from &x T1 inner join &y T2 on
%let sep= ;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&by)) ;
  &sep.T1.%scan(&by,&i)=T2.%scan(&by,&i)
  %let sep=,;
%end;
 ;
quit;
%mend ij  ;
```

Try it:

```
options mprint;
%ij(x=sashelp.class,y=sashelp.class,by=name,to=want,xc=age,yc=height weight);
```

SAS LOG:

```
MPRINT(IJ):   proc sql ;
MPRINT(IJ):   create table want as select T1.name ,T1.age ,T2.height ,T2.weight from sashelp.class
T1 inner join sashelp.class T2 on T1.name=T2.name ;
NOTE: Table WORK.WANT created, with 19 rows and 4 columns.

MPRINT(IJ):   quit;
```

Comment: So much great info, thanks so much. I've been warned against using the native `merge` function as you need to sort the data first and my company went through some drama because of it. But your option on top is quite economic and easier to wrap into a macro as well. I also appreciate the trick for default empty values, definitely an improvement on my ".default" workaround, but is there a reason why you don't write `xc=*` directly in the definition instead ?

Comment: No reason for using the %IF to set defaults for XC and YC.  Note that if you define the macro parameter to allow it to be called by position then there is no way to put a default into the %macro statement.

Comment: Usually SAS shops warn against using PROC SQL joins since they have a much greater risk of causing an full outer join of two large inputs and overwhelming your SAS server's disk space.

Comment: You can avoid the need for sorting prior to a merge if you index your datasets on the key, but that opens up another can of worms as it can change the order in which rows are returned in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of vectors, think simple lists.

Pass your variable lists as unquoted, space separated list of values.  The values are SAS variable names that can be scanned out as tokens.

```
%macro ij (x=, ...);
  ...
  %local i token;
  %let i = 1;
    %do %while (%length(%scan(&X,&i)));
    %let token = %scan(&X,&i);
&token.,/* emit the token as source code */
    %let i = %eval(&i+1);
  %end;
  ...
%mend;

%ij ( x = one two three, ... )
```

Be sure to localize all your macro variables to prevent unwanted side effects outside the macro.

For consistency I try to use i/o related macro parameters that mimic SAS Procs -- `data=`, `out=`, `file=`, ...

Some would say named arguments are verbose!

If your 'proto-code' expects the `xci` symbol to be some sort of serially numbered variable, it is not.  You would have to use `%local xc&i; %let xc&i=` for assignment, and `&&xc&i` for resolution.  Also, your original code references `&from` which is not passed.

Building is fun.  I would also recommend surveying past conference papers and SAS literature for similar works that may already meet your goal.

Comment: Thanks, I think I have a lot of value to take from this piece of code! However I tried to remove the `...` and run it as is and it fails with `ERROR 180-322: Statement is not valid or it is used out of proper order.`. Thanks for your patience I still have to wrap my head around some basics of the language...

Comment: It's not supposed to work when ... is removed.  The ... would be your actual scaffolding around the use.  For your code the innermost &token. , resolutions are in the code generating context of the interior of a SQL selection statement where the variable list from the parameters is being output as comma separated list that SQL syntax requires.

Comment: I didn't mock up full working code because your posted code has the glimmer of someone in the know.

Comment: Oh no I'm not in the know at all, I don't even know where is the know at this point, i'm completely overwhelmed :D. I'll try to integrate this in my proc sql then, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You could start with a space-separated list of column names and avoid looping entirely:

```
/*Define list of columns*/
%let COLS = A  B C;
%put COLS = &COLS;

/*Add table alias prefix*/
%let REGEX = %sysfunc(prxparse(s/(\S+)/t1.$1/));
%let COLS = %sysfunc(prxchange(&REGEX,-1,&COLS));
%put COLS = &COLS;
%syscall prxfree(REGEX);

/*Condense multiple spaces to a single space*/
%let COLS = %sysfunc(compbl(&COLS));
%put COLS = &COLS;

/*Replace spaces with commas*/
%let COLS = %sysfunc(translate(&COLS,%str(,),%str( )));
%put COLS = &COLS;
```

Comment: Thanks, I see in the log that it does the right thing when executing it as is. I've tried to wrap it into a macro by adding `%macro prefix_and_concat(COLS,ti=t1);` on top, removing first line, replacing `t1` by `&ti` and adding `&COLS` and `mend;` in the end. Then in my original code I replaced `t1.&xc` with `%prefix_and_concat(&xc)` but the generated SQL is not good and the join fails.

Comment: I suggest you post this as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

In the end as @Tom noted, SAS dataset options are more convenient, and using them one doesn't need to loop over variables.

Here is the macro I came with :

```
    *--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ;
    * JOIN                                                                                         ;
    * Performs any join (defaults to inner join).                                                  ;
    * By default left table is overwritten (convenient for successive left joins)                  ;
    * Performs a natural join so columns should be renamed accordingly through 'rename' parameters ;
    *----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------;

    %macro join
    (data1=   /* left table */
    ,data2=   /* right table */
    ,keep1=   /* columns to keep (default: keep all), don't use with drop */
    ,keep2=
    ,drop1=   /* columns to drop (default: none), don't use with keep */
    ,drop2=
    ,rename1= /* rename statement, such as 'old1 = new1 old2 = new2 */
    ,rename2=
    ,j=ij     /* join type, either ij lj or rj */
    ,out=     /* created table, by default data1 (left table is overwritten)*/
    );
    %if not %length(&out) %then %let out = &data1;
    %if %length(&keep1)   %then %let keep1 = keep=&keep1;
    %if %length(&keep2)   %then %let keep2 = keep=&keep2;
    %if %length(&drop1)   %then %let drop1 = drop=&drop1;
    %if %length(&drop2)   %then %let drop2 = drop=&drop2;
    %if %length(&rename1) %then %let rename1 = rename=(&rename1);
    %if %length(&rename2) %then %let rename2 = rename=(&rename2);
    %let kdr1 =;
    %let kdr2 =;
    %if (%length(&keep1) | %length(&drop1) | %length(&rename1)) %then %let kdr1 = (&keep1&drop1 &rename1);
    %if (%length(&keep2) | %length(&drop2) | %length(&rename2)) %then %let kdr2 = (&keep2&drop2 &rename2);
    %if &j=lj        %then %let j = LEFT JOIN;
    %if &j=ij        %then %let j = INNER JOIN;
    %if &j=rj        %then %let j = RIGHT JOIN;
    proc sql;
    create table &out as select *
    from &data1&kdr1 t1 natural &j &data2&kdr2 t2;
    quit;
    %mend;
```

Reproducible Examples:

```
data temp1;
input letter $ number1 $;
datalines;
a 1
a 2
a 3
b 4
c 8
;

data temp2;
input letter $ letter2 $ number2 $;
datalines;
a c 666
b d 0
;

* left join on common columns into new table temp3;
%join(data1=temp1,data2=temp2,j=lj,out=temp3)
* inner join by default, overwriting temp 1, after renaming to join on another column;
%join(data1=temp1,data2=temp2,drop2=letter,rename2= letter2=letter)
```